# Group related records in SQL query with Lead/Lag

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given

```
input_fid   near_fid
465         466
465         467
465         468
466         467
466         468
467         468
469         470
470         471
```

How would I go about generating an output of:

```
input_fid   near_fids
465         466,467,468 
469         470,471
```

i.e. get the lowest fid and all the fid's it has a relationship with, avoiding duplication.

Result set is dynamic and the output of a tool that defines relationships between records. So the logic is that 465 is close to 466 and 467 and 468, and 466 is close to 467 to 468 and so forth. But no previous record is close to 469, hence the new row.

Because the result set will be different each time the query is run, I cannot hardcode the query logic.

I have played with various iterations of lead and lag as well as using the WITH statement with varying degrees of success but nothing to make me feel like I'm close. One iteration which got close except for the duplicates was:

`WITH n(input_fid, near_fid, level) AS 
(
    SELECT input_fid, near_fid, 0 as level
    from results
    where input_fid < near_fid
    and input_fid between 465 and 471
    and near_fid between 465 and 471
        UNION ALL
    SELECT m.input_fid, m.near_fid, level + 1
    from results
    where m.input_fid > m.near_fid
    and m.input_fid between 465 and 471
    and m.near_fid between 465 and 471
    and m.near_fid = n.input_fid
)
SELECT input_fid, level, near_fid = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR (MAX), near_fid )
           FROM n b 
           WHERE n.input_fid = b.input_fid
           AND n.level = b.level
           order by near_fid
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM n
where level = 0
GROUP BY input_fid, level`

Comment: "I have played with various iterations of lead and lag ..."  So where's the query???

Comment: How did you generate two  [near_fids] for the [input_fid] value of 469? There's a row with an [input_id] of 469 and a [near_fid] of 470, but no row with an [input_id] of 469 and a [near_fid] of 471. I don't understand your result set

Comment: PausePause - looks like the formatting got borked. Have fixed and added comment.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be what you're after. Not sure I like the fact that I'm scanning the table 3 times though:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (465,466),
                 (465,467),
                 (465,468),
                 (466,467),
                 (466,468),
                 (467,468),
                 (469,470)) V(input_fid, near_fid))
SELECT input_fid,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(3),s.near_fid)
              FROM VTE s
              WHERE s.input_fid = V.input_fid
              ORDER BY s.near_fid
              FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS near_fids
FROM VTE V
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM VTE e
                 WHERE V.input_fid = e.near_fid)
GROUP BY V.input_fid;
```

Note that the outfor for `near_fids` for `input_fid` `469` is only `470`, as your sample data didn't contain any rows, or columns, with the value `471`; so I have no idea where it came from.

Comment: Close! I've updated question with 471. Note that a value may exist in near_fid and not in input_fid that needs to be included in final output.

Comment: Well that changes the game @StevieJ81. How many layers could the hierarchy have?

Comment: The hierarchy is as described I think. If a query can produce the desired output from the above sample data then I believe it meets all my needs.

Comment: Your question doesn't say how many layers there could be. If it's only going to be a max of 2/3 then it'll likely be easier to hard code, but if it could be unlimited, then we either need to go down the rCTE route, or be even more imaginative.

Comment: Ah. No this needs to be dynamic. There is an unknown number of results at execution time.

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest explaining that in your question; as I'm not going to get a chance to write something to handle that so close to the end of the day. Then someone else looking at your question can at least start on the right foot.